# Smart / fast svg fill method

Tags: javascript, svg, fill, flood-fill

[image: Smart/ fast svg fill]

[image: Smart/ fast svg fill 2]

In vector editors, it is possible to fill a segment with color. This creates an additional svg element. Is it possible to implement this on javascript? I am interested in a ready-made solution like a library or method, or an algorithm, how to achieve this.

In search of a solution, I found libraries for finding intersections of paths, but this is not what I need. Svg can be of any shape. What I can control: there will be only path.

Comment: Download and run the code in [this Github gist](https://gist.github.com/shawnbot/8059739). May be something you can use... Interactive Voronoi tesselation demo.

Comment: "_I am interested in a ready-made solution like a **library** or method, or an algorithm, how to achieve this._"  Software recommendation questions are off-topic for reasons explained in #3 of [/help/on-topic](/help/on-topic).

Comment: @RenevanderLende No, with the help of Voronoi's algorithm, it will not be possible to get the "fill" effect, the border of the figure does not pass through the points. Or I need to use it somehow cunningly... I added another photo.